# Working with, preparing bag-of-word data for Regression

Tags: python, text, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

Im trying to create a regression model that predicts an authors age. Im using (Nguyen et al,2011) as my basis.

Using a Bag of Words Model I count the occurences of words per Document (which are Posts from Boards) and create the vector for every Post.

I limit the size of each vector by using as features the top-k (k=number) most frequent used words(stopwords will not be used)

```
Vectorexample_with_k_8 = [0,0,0,1,0,3,0,0]
```

My data is generally sparse like in the Example.

When I test the model on my test data I get a very low r² score(0.00-0.1), sometimes even a negative score. The model predicts always the same age, which happens to be the average age of my dataset, like seen in the
distribution of my data (age/amount):
[image: Agedemographic]

I used diffrerent Regression Models: Linear Regression, Lasso,
SGDRegressor from scikit-learn with no improvement.

So the questions are:

**1.How do I improve the r² score?**

**2.Do I have to change the data to fit the Regression better? If yes with what method?**

**3.Which Regressor/Methods should I use for text classification?**

Comment: Are you saying the model predicts the same age (=average age across *all* documents) for *any* document ?

Comment: This is an interesting problem. Did you ever have any luck?

Answer (score 7):

To my knowledge Bag-of-words models usually use Naive Bayes as classifier to fit the document-by-term sparse matrix.

None of your regressors can handle large sparse matrix well. Lasso may work well if you have groups of highly correlated features.

I think for your problem, [Latent Semantic Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis) may provide better results. Essentially, use the [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) to normalize the word count matrix, then use [TruncatedSVD](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html) to reduce the dimensionality to retain the first N components which capture the major variance. Most regressors should work well with the matrix in lower dimension. In my experimence SVM works pretty good for this problem.

Here I show an example script:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
    ('svd', TruncatedSVD()),
    ('clf', svm.SVR())
])
# You can tune hyperparameters using grid search
params = {
    'tfidf__max_df': (0.5, 0.75, 1.0),
    'tfidf__ngram_range': ((1,1), (1,2)),
    'svd__n_components': (50, 100, 150, 200),
    'clf__C': (0.1, 1, 10),
    }
grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, params, scoring='r2',
    n_jobs=-1, verbose=10)
# fit your documents (Should be a list/array of strings)
grid_search.fit(documents, y)

print("Best score: %0.3f" % grid_search.best_score_)
print("Best parameters set:")
best_parameters = grid_search.best_estimator_.get_params()
for param_name in sorted(parameters.keys()):
    print("\t%s: %r" % (param_name, best_parameters[param_name]))
```