# Speeding Up Support Vector Regression in Sklearn via Parallel Processing

Tags: parallel-processing, scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying to perform support vector regression on some text data in sklearn. I have approximately 10,000 documents that I've transformed into about 30,000 features. The labels are the year that each document's author was born (spread between 1900 and 2016).

I initially tried the SVR class in sklearn but it was taking a very long time. Since I had no clue what if any progress it was making, I decided to switch to use SGDRegressor, which has a nice option to give some intermediate output. Now I can see that the algorithm is making progress, but the convergence is slow. What can I do to speed this up?  One option is to play with the step size/ learning rate, and I'll be doing that presently, but I was wondering if there was any way to use parallel processing to make each step go faster. I can see that the SGDClassifier class has an n_jobs option to take advantage of multiple processors, but I don't see a similar option for the SGDRegressor class.  This strikes me as odd since it seems like SGD can benefit from parallelization.  Are there any libraries that I might benefit from looking at, or ideas about speeding up SVM in sklearn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimension of your feature matrix is apparently too large and sparse. Neither SVR nor SGD can efficiently fit such a large matrix. A general rule-of-thumb, models are prone to over-fitting when the number of features exceed the number of examples.

I suggest using TruncatedSVD to reduce the dimensionality of your matrix and train SVR.

Here I shamelessly promote my own answer: [Working with, preparing bag-of-word data for Regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510014/working-with-preparing-bag-of-word-data-for-regression/37528225#37528225)